# Locking a database table in RoR and python

Tags: python, mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sqlalchemy

I am trying to synchronize the MySQL access of two processes/programs. One is written in RoR and other in Python.

`Database : MySQL`
`Python ORM Tool : sqlalchemy`
`RoR Gem : Active Records`

Out of all the tables in the database, only one of them can be written by both the programs. Can I somehow lock the whole table in the database so that I don't corrupt the data in the table?

Comment: It is not recommended to share access between two different ORMs, especially convention-driven.  Try to avoid it at any cost.  Is there a reason why you do not want to have 2 tables and share data via web services?

Comment: @Godsaur - I want to start a ***backup*** server side process. This process can be started by the admin using front-end(RoR) or by a cron job(python). If ***backup*** process is running, it should not be started again.

Comment: Can't you just have the python cron job hit the rails URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LOCK TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html) and/or [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html).